# Magento EE - restrict access to media folder if user not logged in

Tags: magento

I want to restrict access to resources (pdf, doc, docx, etc.) files to users who have logged in.

The resources are located under /var/www/html/media/wysiwyg/...

So, if someone tries to access the URL `http://domain/media/wysiwyg/sales.pdf`, I want to redirect them to the login page if they aren't logged in.

I was planning on using a .htaccess rewrite and wrap all access attempts to the restricted files through a .php program that would check if the user is logged in or not - but I am not sure how to check the user's logged in status.

I tried:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app('', ''); 

//GET SESSION DATA

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

if($session->isLoggedIn()){
// send data
}
else
{
// redirect to login page
}
```

but isLoggedIn() is always false.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this depends on your specifications but I wonder why taking care of this from a media directory , while you already have the [downloadable product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/how_to_create_a_downloadable_product) option

- you can set it from your admin panel
- customize it by customer role
- make it as free product
- limit the downloading times number
- you can even bundle it with other products ( in case of you are selling a machine with its docs  )

I guess all your needs in it , if there is something you need is not implemented feel free to and extend and write your own

if you ever come for an update to your question , please update it and I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    // send data
}
else {
    // redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The downloadable product option does not quite fit with our needs - we have lots of resource pages that get updated, and new files get uploaded to the media folder.

In doing some more research, I figured out how to test if there is a logged in user or not:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
  // there is a customer id, so someone is logged in
  // send the file
}
else
{
   // redirect to login page, or a page that explains why the link doesn't work
}
```

If you want to obtain information about the logged in user, you have to actually use the loginById method first:

```
if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
   $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];

   // Load the user session.
   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);

   $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

   // Load customer
   $customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();
}
```

A lot of solutions that show up when you search for how to verify if a customer is logged in, show the use of the isLoggedIn() method of the $customerSession, but if you don't 'log in' using the cusotmerId and loginById method, the isLoggedIn method will always return false.